# Select all columns except one column in CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have an orders table there are more than 30 columns. I want to show all the column except `attribute` column from my `orders` table.

We all know that to select all columns for specific id from a table, we can use

```
$data = $this->Order->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Order.id'=>1)));
```

Can you please tell me how to write query in CakePHP 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you will gain much by excluding the column from your query. If you really need to do this then you can get the [model's schema](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-Model.html#_schema) and then remove the column from that and then use the remaining columns in your `find()` by defining the fields you want returned by the query:-

```
// Get the model’s schema.
$schema = $this->Order->schema();
// Remove the `attribute` column from the schema.
unset($schema['attribute']);
// Determine the remaining columns from the schema.
$cols = array_keys($schema);

// Now call your query specifying the fields you want back using the 
// columns we’ve just determined.
$data = $this->Order->find('first', 
    array(
        'fields' => $cols,
        'conditions' => array('Order.id' => 1)
    )
);
```

Comment: Ok. Let me check your answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use [getColumnTypes()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getcolumntypes) here:

```
$fields = array_keys($this->Order->getColumnTypes());  /* Returns an associative array of field names and column types*/
$key = array_search('attribute', $fields);             /* Search the key having attribute field */
unset($fields[$key]);         /* Remove the key value pair corresponding to attribute */
$this->Order->find('all', array('fields' => $fields));  /* Apply search specifying the fields */
```